# Unable to Consistently get mapViewdidSelectView function called on a custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotation

When creating a custom `MKAnnotationView`, called `GroupUserAnnotationView`, it is only registering the tapping on the bottom part of the annotation, but not the top. I've tried to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the annotation view, but it did not work.

Creating the annotation view:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView!
        var annotationIdentifier: String!
        
        if annotation.isKind(of: GroupUserAnnotation.self) {
            annotationIdentifier = "groupUser"
            annotationView = GroupUserAnnotationView(annotation: annotation as! GroupUserAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView.frame = (annotationView as! GroupUserAnnotationView).containerView.frame
    
        } else {
            annotationIdentifier = "marker"
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        }
        
        
        return annotationView
    }
```

The `GroupUserAnnotationView`:

```
class GroupUserAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var email: String!
    var image: UIImage!
}

class GroupUserAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    public lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -40, y: -70, width: 70, height: 70))
        view.backgroundColor = .accentColor
        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.width / 2
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return view
    }()
    
    public lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = (annotation as! GroupUserAnnotation).image!
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()
    
    public lazy var bottomCornerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .accentColor
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return view
    }()
    
    // MARK: Initialization
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation as! GroupUserAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    public func setupView() {
        subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
        
        containerView.addSubview(bottomCornerView)
        bottomCornerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        bottomCornerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
        bottomCornerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
        bottomCornerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
        
        let angle = (39.0 * CGFloat.pi) / 180
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        bottomCornerView.transform = transform
        
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 2.0).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 2.0).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -2.0).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -2.0).isActive = true
        
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = (containerView.frame.size.width - 1) / 2
        
    }
```

And again, only the bottom part of the annotation is actually registering (which means that I have properly implemented the `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` delegate function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is even worse: the tap is recognised by the map behind your UIView and causes unintended actions.

The workaround that works for me is using enabled `UIControl`s instead of `UIView`s.

This can be a `UIButton`s that you use directly as buttons, or an invisible enabled large button in the background and `UIView`s on top.

The big invisible `UIButton` in the background has the task of preventing taps going through to the map.

Use smaller visible buttons on top for normal user interaction, if needed.

Comment: Bit confused, should I add a transparent `UIButton` to the back of my custom annotation view?

Comment: I added some clarification when do use which type of button.